# How to remove the top line with highcharts on flutter

Tags: flutter, highcharts

how to remove this xasix top line

[image]

i want to be like this :

[image]

i read a lot of highcharts documents ,but i can't found the answer,I wonder if you have any solutions

my highchars code is:

```
{
    xAxis: {
      lineWidth :0,//去掉x轴线
        categories: $xAxisData,
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        gridLineColor: '#808080',
        title: {
            enabled: false
        },
    labels: {
        style: {
            color: '#ffffff'
        }
    }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
      lineWidth: 1,
      lineColor: '#808080',
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    gridLineColor: '#808080',
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
      style: {
            color: '#ffffff',
            fontSize: 12
      }
    }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled:false
    },
    tooltip: {
        split: false,
        valueSuffix: '条'
    },
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

remove the x axais top line

Comment: which dependency  you use for this?

Comment: Be aware that the HighChart products used by some packages in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: Highcharts are open-source product and license it's free for non-comercial use, if you doubt about your case of use you can send ask directly to the `sales@highsoft.com`.

Comment: Free for "limited-use" does not meet the definition of "open source" as held by the stewards of the term, the Open Source Initiative.  What I said is precisely accurate, and an appropriate call to action for whom that is important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [styled mode](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.styledMode) to hide grid line on yaxis, article of [how to style by css](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css#style-by-css). Catch the last element using CSS pseudo-class [:last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) and choose how to hide visibility `stroke: transparent;` or `stroke: transparent;`.

```
.highcharts-yaxis-grid path:last-of-type {
  /* stroke: transparent; */
  stroke-width: 0px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xdrj846h/